# Reading same BAM file twice with htslib

Tags: htslib

I would like to read iteratively the same BAM file twice using `htslib`.

My option is to use `hts_open`, `sam_hdr_read`, then `sam_read1` as much as needed to read the file until EOF.

Is there a possibility to "rewind", and use `sam_read1` again from the beginning of the file, without closing the file, destroying the object, and opening it again?

---

**EDIT**

My aim is group the reads by the barcode.  The first pass would allocate the specific sizes first (the number of reads by barcode), then store the reads.

I know I could sort the reads first (using `samtools sort -t BX`), but I would like to skip this step using pre-allocation.

Comment: @M__ Thanks, I edited the question.  I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to reopen the file. For a coordinate sorted file you have the option to jump back to the start of the first chromosome with index but that is more complex, less flexible and won't be faster.